# Elegant way of doing interlanguage data exchange

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a socket server which I am writing in C++ and a client which I have written in C#, now I want to send messages between them. I was considering de-serializing 'message' objects to xml and creating object instances across the wire and it looks like a elegant way to do things rather than string/xml parsing but I am open to new ideas, and if anyone has done this before would like to hear your experience, also will this work for data exchange between C# and C++ (Compiled with Microsoft VS but without .NET support)?

Thanks,

Deepak.

Comment: Did you look at [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much dissonance is caused by the change in languages, but if you want a "platform-independent" way to do it, you could try [protocol buffers.](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)